# MySQL: Find successive rows, where timestamp difference is less than x

Tags: mysql

> Duplicate of [Mysql: Find rows, where timestamp difference is less than x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513983/mysql-find-rows-where-timestamp-difference-is-less-than-x)

I have table as follows:

```
Field       Type
id              int(11)
user            varchar(64)
date        int(11)
key             int(11)
```

Date is in time stamp format. 
I'm looking for a way, to find all rows, where time stamp difference between successive rows is smaller than x. Is it possible?

Comment: Is is autoincremental?

Comment: In one SQL statement? Tricky, but with the use of variables one might give it a try. Post test data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql: Find rows, where timestamp difference is less than x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513983/mysql-find-rows-where-timestamp-difference-is-less-than-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, assuming timestamp means `date`.  Here is a version that uses a correlated subquery to get the next `date` value:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select date
              from yourtable t2
              where t2.date > t.date
              order by t2.date
              limit 1
             ) as NextDate
      from yourtable t
     ) t
where <difference calculation goes here>;
```

EDIT:

The above is standard SQL.  In MySQL you can also do this using variables.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, @nextdate as nextdate, @nextdate := date
      from yourtable t
      order by date desc
     ) t
where <difference calculation goes here>;
```

There are two issues that I have with this approach.  First, the use of variables requires sequential processing of the result set (not a big deal in MySQL because I think this happens anyway).  More importantly, the order of evaluation on the `select` is not guaranteed.  In other words, this probably works, but it is not guaranteed to work.

By the way, many other databases support the `lead()` function which would be the "right" way to do this.  Unfortunately, MySQL does not support window functions.

Comment: And date difference should look like "t2.date - t2.date < 1000" (for example), or is there a better way?

Comment: @PsychoX . . . `datediff()` or substraction gets you the difference in days.  If you need a more refined unit then `timediff()` is what you need.  Or, you can convert to a Unix Timestamp.  There are (too) many ways to get a difference in date/timees in MySQL so I left this intentionally open.

Comment: Hmm... unfortunately this query is too slow. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @PsychoX . . . add an index on `yourtable(date)`.  That will help it a lot.

Comment: One more question. Could You please post example difference calculation? I'm not sure how to deal with variables. For example difference could be smaller than 1000.

Comment: If it should look like "nextdate - t.date < 1300", then I don't get any results.

Comment: @PsychoX . . . I don't know what it means for an `int(11)` to be in "time stamp format".  I would suggest that you use `TIMESTAMP` or `datetime` as appropriate for your problem.

Comment: Could You show me how do difference calculation with date column in timestamp format? I just want to see how example comparison will look like.

Comment: @PsychoX . . . The function `unix_timestamp()` converts it to seconds since some date in the past.  You can then take the difference in seconds for the difference calculation.

Comment: I mean something else. I'm trying to get some rows from this query and I have troubles with this. I'm not sure if I know how to use variables. Is it correct to write comparison like: "t.nextdate - t.date < 1300"? Should it in theory return some rows?